# How to set open cart banner to full width

Tags: opencart

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdGAg.jpg

I am getting full with for banner images. I did set 100% width for container class

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set `background-size` in your css as

```
background-size: cover;
```

For more info read this [**`Mozilla docs`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) or follow this [**`post`**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)